# jQuery add Custom validation which Validate a group of fields as required only when at least one of them is filled else skip

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery add Custom validation which Validate a group of fields as required only when at least one of them is filled else skip

Validation check only when at least on of the input fields is not empty (filled)

Fill all fields or nothing

Comment: Can you add whatever code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you are using [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). untested but something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("required_if_filled", function(value, element) {

  // if alle are empty, let validation pass
  if($("#other_element").val() === "" && $("#another_element").val() === "" && ...) {
    return true;
  } // or instead of many selectors use foreach on all radio buttons within a div or something like that. depends on what you really need

  // return true if it is not empty
  return (value !== "")
}, "Your error message");
```

use it like this `<input type="text" class="required_if_filled" />`

Comment: yes m using jquery validate. Instead of accessing element by its ID (that's what i don't want) can't we access by variable in function --->( function(value, element) ) ....something like group validate.

Comment: you can go from the element to the closest container and iterate over all inputs in that container (or group as you said) ```$(element).closest("something").find("input").each(...```

Comment: i dont't know of any build in grouping in jquery validate